# Build a Zip Code Proximity Search with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form that looks up near by doctors based on distance and zip code.

The following is the form:

```
<form name="DoctorSearch" novalidate role="form">
<div style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:15px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">
    <strong>OR<br> SEARCH BY ZIP CODE RADIUS </strong>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <select id="miles" name="distance">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=""></option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
    <span style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; resize: vertical; margin-left: -3px; font-size: 15px;">     
        miles
    </span>
    <span style="margin-left:30px">
        <input name="zip" allow-pattern="[\d\W]" id="zip" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" />
    </span>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:70px">
    <div style="float:left">
        <input onclick="return checkTextField();" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">
        <input type="reset" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.testsite.com';" value ="Reset" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I was able to write a query that looks up the doctors based on zip code (see below). However, I am not sure how to determine everything within a 
specific range (miles / kilometers). How can I achieve this?

```
<cfset name_list1 = "UICC">   
<cfset name_list2 = "Medi-Cal"> 
<cfset name_list3 = "RMG,RCMG,RFMG">      
<cfquery name="DoctorSearch" datasource="source">
SELECT Distinct officeCity, officeName, officeAddressLine1, officeState, officeZipCode, officephone, OfficeHours 
FROM DocList
where utilizedspecialty in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list1#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
    and network not like (<cfqueryparam value="#'%name_list2%'#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
    and Company in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list3#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">) 
    and officeZipCode like '%#zip#%'
order by officeCity
</cfquery>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use a mapping API.

Comment: @Miguel-F: Not sure how to implement it and any example to guide me to the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Well it's kind of complicated. Here is a link to the developer documentation for Google's maps api and specifically the distance matrix api which can be used to calculate distances between locations on a map. [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Comment: @Miguel-F: Thank you. I just dont know how to implement that in coldfusion. thanks for the help though

Comment: @user9808783, if you have a table mapping ZIP codes to coordinates (latitude, longitude) then there are formulas you can use to find ZIP codes within a certain radius of another ZIP code. Then you get the matching records. Or you might be using a database that allows for spatial searching.

Comment: A simple search turns up how to use the Google API with CF: https://cfdeepak.wordpress.com/2014/09/13/geocoding-with-google-map-api-and-coldfusion/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bunch of complicated math. I've used code from this package: https://github.com/cfmaniac/CF-Locator
But that entire package may be what you need. It does radius searching.

Answer (score 0):

Like somebody said above, you'll need a table that associates zips with lat/lng values. You'll want to find zips the are within x miles of the given zip. This is how I did it recently. The function below first calls a query to get the lat/lng for the provided zip. Then it creates a range of lat/lng values that are within x miles of the provided zip. Finally, it calls a query that finds all zips within that range of lat/lng values, and returns those zips. With that list, you could then go find doctors located in that range of zips.

```
public any function getZips (required string zip, required numeric miles) {
    rs = searchGateway.getCoordinatesByZip(zip);
    if (!rs.recordcount) {
        return [zip];
    }
    half = (miles / 2);
    maxLat = (rs.lat + (half * 0.01666));
    minLat = (rs.lat - (half * 0.01666));
    maxLng = (rs.lng + (half * 0.01886));
    minLng = (rs.lng - (half * 0.01886));
    return searchGateway.getZipsByCoordinates(maxLat, minLat, maxLng, minLng);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just make the cfhttp calls with the relevant zips, and interpret the responses.

Between cf docs and gaps api docs you should be able to get there.